# How to resize form to fit DataGridView?

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, resize

I have a form that contains dataGridView, whose coloumn are set to

dgrv1.Width =dgrv1.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)+20;

I want to make the form to automaticaly follow the width of dataGridView...

Also, on maximized, I would like it to grow in height only.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have got a Width value. Set both the MaximumSize and MinimuSize properties of the Form to that value. Maybe with a little margin in between.

Leave the Max/Min Height properties on `0` for default.

Additional:

this gives me a Form that can only be 200 width, but the default '0' for height seems not to work.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MinimumSize = new Size(200, 400);
        this.MaximumSize = new Size(200, 1200);

    }
```

Comment: "Set both the MaximumSize and MinimuSize properties of the Form to that value"----how do I do that???
I've tried next:  

this.MaximumSize.Width = dgrv1.Width + 20;
this.MinimumSize.Width = dgrv1.Width + 20;   

where "this" is a form...    
what is a problem there?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the main form's OnChange event?

```
    private void MainForm_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Width = ...;
        this.Height = ...;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean:
private void MainForm_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Width = ...;
        this.Height = ...;
    }
?????